# Finding whether a number of the form 1444....4 is a perfect square

Tags: java, mathematics

Someone asked me

> We know that \$12^2 = 144\$ and that \$38^2 = 1444\$. Are there any other perfect squares in the form?

Here is my code:

```
public class OneFours {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    final int power_of_ten = 8;
    int num = 14;
    for (int i = 0; i <= Math.pow(10, power_of_ten); i++) {
        if (Math.pow((int) Math.sqrt(num), 2) == num) {
            System.out.println(num + " is a perfect square with root "
                    + Math.sqrt(num));
        }
        if (i % (Math.pow(10, power_of_ten) / 100) == 0)
            System.out.println("--- Progress "
                    + (int)((i / Math.pow(10, power_of_ten)) * 100) + "% complete");
        num = num * 10 + 4;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This thread might be interesting in this context: [Fastest way to determine if an integer's square root is an integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295579/fastest-way-to-determine-if-an-integers-square-root-is-an-integer), in particular this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18686659/1187415.

Comment: Using PARI/GP I verified that there are no other perfect squares of the form 144...44 with less than 1 million digits :)

Comment: @MartinR so what is the square root of 144444444444444444444444444444 ? :)

Comment: @Caridorc: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28144444444444444444444444444444%29

Comment: @MartinR thanks Python ** 0.5 gave me an integer because I run into a float approximation problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you modularize your code writing a function to check for perfect squares:

```
public static boolean isPerfectSquare(int n) {
    return Math.pow((int) Math.sqrt(n), 2) == n;
}
```

And you then you can call it:

```
if (isPerfectSquare(num)) {
                System.out.println(num + " is a perfect square with root "
                    + Math.sqrt(num));
            }
```

---

You should also take care of always putting braces, namely

```
    if (i % (Math.pow(10, power_of_ten) / 100) == 0)
        System.out.println("--- Progress "
                + (int)((i / Math.pow(10, power_of_ten)) * 100) + "% complete");
```

should become

```
    if (i % (Math.pow(10, power_of_ten) / 100) == 0) {
        System.out.println("--- Progress "
                + (int)((i / Math.pow(10, power_of_ten)) * 100) + "% complete");
    }
```

typing braces takes  a fraction of a second, fixing bugs caused by not writing them may take hours.

---

And make sure you get your indentation correct, after some tweaking in my ide I your code looks like this:

```
public class OneFours {
    public static boolean isPerfectSquare( int n) {
        return Math.pow((int) Math.sqrt(n), 2) == n;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final int power_of_ten = 8;
        int num = 14;
        for (int i = 0; i <= Math.pow(10, power_of_ten); i++) {
            if (isPerfectSquare(num)) {
                System.out.println(num + " is a perfect square with root "
                    + Math.sqrt(num));
            }
            if (i % (Math.pow(10, power_of_ten) / 100) == 0) {
                System.out.println("--- Progress "
                    + (int)((i / Math.pow(10, power_of_ten)) * 100) + "% complete");
            }
            num = num * 10 + 4;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: another problem is the limit of int data type or long data type is reached at 1444..44 with around 10 or 18th iteration.

Comment: @ADG that is important enough to be a separate answer

Answer (score 3):

`Math.pow()` returns a `double`, which you're comparing with an `int`.  Plus, it's not good to have a decimal value in a `for` loop statement.  As such, you may need to implement your own function for this that returns an integer type instead of a decimal type.

You can then make its returned value `final` since your code already doesn't change this value.  This will avoid the need to call the function each time through the loop since it never changes.

Comment: Are you sure about `num *= 10 + 4`?

Comment: @200_success: I suppose I'm not, so I'll just remove it.  Is there anything else wrong with it?

Comment: *"Plus, it's not good to have a decimal value in a for loop statement"* Elaborate please. What is a decimal value in this case and why is it not good to have in a for-loop statement?